# Azure Data Factory - Unable to preview data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF pipeline that uses basic transformations in a data flow. As such the data flow is pretty straightforward, nothing much complex going on here. Only a couple of lookups and derived columns.

It was working fine until earlier today but since afternoon the preview of output data at each step in timing out. One of the lookup tables has about 7 million records but it was still showing up fine until earlier today. I changed the row limits in the Debug settings but still the output data preview is timing out, without any results.
Even the data preview of the derived columns is timing out.

I thought of running the pipeline anyway to see what gets loaded into the final table. But that failed because apparently the derived column is getting some NULL values and is passing that on to to a NOT NULL field in the SINK's table structure. So, now I really need to preview the step output.

The data preview is taking really long and then just errors out with a time out error. Please suggest if there anyway to change the performance of the ADF.

Comment: Can you share the error message or snips as well ? this maybe due to many reasons, just to be sure if nothing has changed from your previous runs, check back all linked service connections are success and inspect tabs in individual activities to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much details into your setup, it is hard to answer accurately.

However, as explained here in MS doc for [Internal server errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide#internal-server-errors)

> Successful execution of data flows depends on many factors,
> including the compute size/type, numbers of source/sinks to process,
> the partition specification, transformations involved, sizes of
> datasets, the data skewness and so on.

Further looking at troubleshooting tips [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide#miscellaneous-troubleshooting-tips)

> There maybe a high number of null values or missing values which may
> be caused by having too few rows sampled. Try updating the debug row
> limit and refreshing the data.

For more guidance, see  [Integration Runtime performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime-performance).

From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide#:%7E:text=the%20data%20preview.-,Recommendation,-%3A%20In%20Debug%20Settings), **Recommendation**:

Go to **Debug Settings**, increase the number of rows in the source row limit. Select an Azure IR that has a data flow cluster that's large enough to handle more data.

Even though integration runtime has compute resources elastically allocated, you can manually [setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime) a new Integration runtime with higher capacity.

[image]

Also, since you mention of millions of records, when you have a pipeline with data flows executing in parallel or data flows that need to be tested with large datasets, choose "**Use Activity Runtime**" so that the service can use the Integration Runtime that you've selected in your data flow activity. This will allow the data flows to execute on multiple clusters and can accommodate your parallel data flow executions.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to speed up the Data Preview results? It takes forever to Refresh data even on a very small data set. I’m talking about 3 records from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There are typically two methods I use to make data previews "render faster", and if those fail, another method for examining data:

1. Use an expression on your SQL source with optional filters built in. (Only works for SQL sources or other sources you can formulate a query on). This method is most efficient.

   1. Identify a "filter column" that you can typically use to reduce row volume. For example a "Sales Order Number" column, or a date.
   2. Create a parameter on the data flow for this filter column. Default it to an expression that evaluates to a null value, like "toString(null())". In my example, I will call this parameter "SalesOrderFilter"
   3. In your source transform, use an expression to build a query - typically a "SELECT *" type query. In that expression, use "$SalesOrderFilter" to optionally filter the resultset. Such as
      "SELECT * FROM [Schema].[Table]" + if(isNull($SalesOrderFilter), "", "WHERE [Sales Order] = '" + $SalesOrderFilter + "')"
   4. At preview time, set the Debug Settings to change the default parameter value to the value you wish to filter to.
2. Manually build a subset of rows into a separate database/lake/tables and switch to those for debugging. This is less usable than above - more manual labour - but is computationally efficient.
3. Throw a simple Filter transform into the stream as early as possible. This can be completely temporary for your current editing session. This works on any source, but isn't as efficient as the first solution because the cluster still reads all (sample) rows, then filters them.
4. If all else fails or is too cumbersome to implement - the simplest alternative is to "add a branch and a new sink with recreate table to a temp table"

   1. Press the "+" button on the transform you would have wanted to preview, but can't.
   2. Add a sink, configure it to write wherever you like.
   3. If it's a SQL table, enable the "recreate table" option.
   4. Run the flow from a pipeline. Your complete dataset will be written out. If it's SQL, the table will be created with NVARCHAR(MAX) NULLABLE columns, so no runtime errors.